# Magento 2 Rest Api as JSON

Tags: magento2, rest-api

i need to return the response of custom web api as JSON.

i need it to be like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}
```

however, my module is coming out as

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
]
```

My Interface is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Mag\Rest\Api;

interface OrdersManagementInterface
{
  /**
   * GET for Stock api
   * @param mixed $items
   * @return string
   */
  public function getOrders();

}
```

My model is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Mag\Rest\Model;

use \stdClass;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 */

class OrdersManagement
{
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(
    ) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $configLoader = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface");
        $objectManager->configure($configLoader->load('frontend')); 
        $this->connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDelayedOrders()
    {
        $sql = "Select *  FROM custom_order";
        $results = $this->connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $results ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload all of your the code in your getOrders method?

Comment: i updated the code, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Update the getDelayedOrders method to:

```
public function getDelayedOrders()
{
    $sql = "Select *  FROM custom_order";
    $delayedOrders = $this->connection->fetchAll($sql);
    $result = ['data' => $delayedOrders];

    return $result;
}
```